# Flyway migration: make flyway stop looking for already migrated files

Tags: spring-boot, migration, flyway

i am currently working on More than one porject that shares the same database but each one has it's own puporse. They are not regrouped by a gateway, they a just 3 standalone project.
So every project has it's own entities and should and own migration files that others do not have. But when i wan to run a migration a project_2, flyway says that it does not locate the migration file that is in project_1. How can i tell it not to do this check and just apply the migration.

I know that putting one standalone in charge of all migrations would solve the issue but that is not the purpose here as they can be deployed independetly from one another and a change in one standalone shall not affect the runing of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this problem because flyway uses `history` table that it creates inside of your DB in order to check for migrations applied.

In order to avoid conflicts you should define a separate schema and/or table names for flyway to use.

As described in [docu](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/flyway/exploring-the-flyway-schema-history-table#ChangeFSHConfig), create a `flyway.conf` in you project and define values for each project:

```
# Name of Flyway's schema history table (default: flyway_schema_history)
# By default (single-schema mode) the schema history table is placed in the default schema for the connection
# provided by the datasource.
# When the flyway.schemas property is set (multi-schema mode), the schema history table is placed in the first
# schema of the list.
flyway.table=MigrationHistory
flyway.placeholders.historyTable=MigrationHistory
flyway.schemas=flyway,dbo,classic,people
flyway.defaultSchema=flyway
```